# How can I read all the plain text from a website with Python?

Tags: python, json, web, python-requests

I am trying to make my code print all the plain text from a website. This is my code:

```
import requests
import json
response = requests.get("https://example.com")
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
print(str(json_data))
```

For example: if I enter `https://example.com`, I want to make the program write

```
Example Domain

This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.

More information...
```

But I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you calling `json.loads()`?  Website responses typically aren't in json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://example.com"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
# delete unwanted elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()  

# get actual text
text = soup.get_text()


lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)
```

don't forget to first **pip install beautifulsoup4**